# Where is the term "Mate" from, and why is it used only in certain areas

Tags: meaning

Also any linguists approaches or theories on the lexical term mate will be appreciated.
When I say mate I am referring to the term when speaking of a friend.

Comment: ***Mate*** with what meaning? The full OED has 8 separate entries for the "word", with at least half-a-dozen different etymologies.

Comment: ...one that definitely has "regional variations" is for the sense *companion, fellow, comrade, friend; a fellow worker or business partner*, apparently from *Middle Low German **māt** comrade*. You won't often hear an American greet you with anything like *Hi, mate! How's tricks?*, but it's certainly a common enough colloquialism in the UK or Oz.

Comment: In the absence of clarification (which meaning are you asking about) this question should probably be closed as *unclear what you're asking*. I haven't voted to close it yet, to give you a chance to add this - it's an interesting question if you mean the definition other comments have guessed at.

Comment: Related: *[Geographical Usage of “Mate”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/206151)*

Comment: An LL classic: *[Why don't Americans say "mate"?](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3380)*

Answer (score 5):

**Mate** originally meant "[sharer of food](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mate#Etymology_1)", Old English *ġemetta*. It's related to the words "meat" and "mess". So, semantic change to mean "friend", "lover", "assistant", "match" is not a very far stretch from the original meaning of "food-sharer".

(As to why it's only used in certain areas, that's just from normal variation of dialects. It's also used in various forms in many other Germanic languages. )

Answer (score -4):

Not a native english nor a linguist but isn't this word coming from "teammate" and has a similar meaning as "partner" ?

Comment: Other way around.

Comment: Please [edit] to add [citations to reliable sources](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) that support the assertions made here. Unsourced material may be disputed or [deleted](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).